# Unable to save data using entity frame work code first technique

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am unable to save data using code first technique.
here is my context:

```
    public virtual DbSet<Users> User { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Agency> Agencies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ColdStorage> ColdStorages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ShowRoom> ShowRooms { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
```

and my user model is here:

```
    [Table("Users")]
      public class Users
     {
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool isAgency { get; set; }
    public bool isColdStorage { get; set; }
    public string VerificationCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }
    public virtual ColdStorage ColdStorage { get; set; }
    public virtual ShowRoom ShowRoom { get; set; }

    public Users()
    {
        Agency = new Agency();
        ColdStorage = new ColdStorage();
        ShowRoom = new ShowRoom();
    }
}
```

and my other model is here:

```
  [Table("Agency")]
  public class Agency
  {
    [Key]
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string AgencyName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }//Foriegn key
}
```

And the error is here:

> Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nColdStorage_Users_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ColdStorage_Users_Source' in relationship 'ColdStorage_Users'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.\r\nShowRoom_Users_Source:

Comment: If agency has UserId it can only point to one user. 

Start by:

1. Deleting `[Required]` on 

     [Required]
     public virtual Users Users { get; set; }//Foriegn key

2. Deleting `UserId`


     [ForeignKey("Users")]
     public int UserId { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says.

> "because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the
>   upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'"

The "Dependent Role properties" here means, eg Agency.UserId, and the "multiplicity must be '*'" means Users must have a collection of Agencies.  EG

```
public virtual ICollection<Agency> Agencies { get; } = new HashSet<Agency>();
```